# Use of Instance Variables & self.variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

The ruby gem [BCrypt](http://bcrypt-ruby.rubyforge.org/) has an example of how to use one of it's modules. Taken from the docs:

```
def password
  @password ||= Password.new(self.password_hash)
end

def password=(new_password)
  @password = Password.create(new_password)
  self.password_hash = @password
end
```

Why would we use the instance variable `@password` at all when we have the `self.password_hash` attribute? I feel like I am missing something, probably due to my inexperience with ruby. Personally, I would have accomplished what I believe to be the same with:

```
def password
  self.password_hash ||= Password.new(self.password_hash)
end

def password=(new_password)
  self.password_hash = Password.create(new_password)
end
```

Comment: I started to answer - but then realized, you are right, it is a bit strange. I think we'd have to investigate the surrounding context to figure out what the difference is between `@password` and `#password_hash`. I would think your method would work, but there may be other side effects that require these two to be allowed to differ, sometimes. The only thing I can tell for sure is that `@password` is always a Password instance, but it appears `#password_hash` _can be_, but does not appear as if it _always would be_. Is there an alterate way to call `#password_hash=`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is as follows: password hash is a string - a hash of the password. However `Password.new(self.password_hash)` creates new object of the `Password` class. Thus the difference: `String` vs `Password`. You can call methods such as `cost`, `version` etc. on the `Password` object, which are unavailable for `String`.

I guess you find the following method strange:

```
def password=(new_password)
  @password = Password.create(new_password)
  self.password_hash = @password
end
```

but what happens here, which is not obvious is the conversion of the `Password` object to `String` object in the `self.password_hash` assignment - the `to_s` method returns the hash of the password and that value is stored in the database. What is more - the `@password` instance variable is set, so the `password` method will return an instance of `Password` class, not the password hash `String`.

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense. looking back at docs, it does state that `self.password_hash` is a `:string` in the database. +1